# BMI Button checked for gender

Tags: java, android, if-statement, button

I have a code where I'm stuck on something I don't know how to do.
I have to develop an app in java of ideal weight, where male calculates (72.7*height) - 58 and female calculates  (62.1*height) - 44.7.
I created a radio button for sex, but I don't know where to put the if code below that I found. I appreciate the help

activity_main.xml

```
 <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rgSexo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbMasculino"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Masculino" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbFeminino"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Feminino" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

mainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        double altura;
        double resp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText etAltura = findViewById(R.id.etAltura);
        Button btnCalc = findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
        final TextView tvResp = findViewById(R.id.tvResp);



        // Botão para calcular
        btnCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    double imc = calcIMC( Double.parseDouble(etAltura.getText().toString()));
                    imcString(imc, tvResp);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Erro:",e.toString());
                    tvResp.setText(getText(R.string.err));
                }
                hideKeyBoard();
            }
        });

    }



    // Cálculo do IMC
    private double calcIMC( double altura){
        


        double resp = (72.7*altura)-58;
        return resp;
    }



    // Obtem cálculo e formula resposta
    private void imcString(double calc,TextView tv){
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        String resp = "Seu peso ideal é: "+df.format(calc)+"\n";

        tv.setText(resp);
    }
```

The question is, where exactly I'll put this

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v)
    {
        //require to import the RadioButton class
        RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Radio_one);
        RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Radio_two);

        //is the current radio button now checked?
        boolean  checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();

        //now check which radio button is selected
        //android switch statement
        switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.Radio_one:
                if(checked)
                    //if first selected
                break;

            case R.id.Radio_two:
                if(checked)
                    //if second selected

                break; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a function that you override so u put it in your MainActivity class
like a function

You don't call this function in your onCreate, It's called when the user click the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Change the btnCalc clickListener to this:

```
RadioButton rbMasculino = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.rbMasculino);
btnCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean isMale = rbMasculino.isChecked();
        try{
            double imc = calcIMC(Double.parseDouble(etAltura.getText().toString()), isMale);
            imcString(imc, tvResp);
            }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Erro:",e.toString());
            tvResp.setText(getText(R.string.err));
            }
        }
    });
```

And change your calcIMC method to this.

```
public double calcIMC(double height, boolean isMale) {
    // true for male, false for female
    if (isMale) {
        return (72.7 * height) - 58;
    } else {
        return (62.1 * height) - 44.7;
    }
}
```

What I did was just check the male radio button, and pass that boolean to the calculator method. Method checks if boolean is true and false, returns the value accordingly.